# Nesting or reusing display template engine

Tags: 2013, client-side-rendering

In a corporate application, I have a custom list with this structure:

- a document set derived content type. Let's call it "**container**". This content type has some metadata: **kind**, **target**, ...
- a custom document derived content type, "**containee**" for documents within the "**container**".

I want to build a page, that allows me to search for these **containers**.

To reach this goal, I set up a classic `ResultScriptWebPart` in my page, and some refiner webparts.

The search and refinement is working. However, I need to present to the user both the **container** and the **containee** data, in the **same** view (child item can be loaded asynchronously).

My question is:

### **Is there any way to display content of a document set directly within the search results ?**

### **Is it possible to create display template for these nested data?**

I found [an article that talks about inner template](http://www.mbgreen.com/blog/2013/6/20/how-render-an-inner-display-template-in-sharepoint), however I think this works only with the same set of data than the parent template.

As a workaround, I handle this requirement in a custom script. I wrote a "expandable" jQuery plugin that allows me to "expand" a result. I catch the expand operation to call a JSOM method and populate myself the sub items, but it has some lacks:

- awful to write and read
- output html is hard coded. Would be preferable to separate the markup in a dedicated display template (more reusable and maintainable)

Finally, I also think about creating a custom content processor in which I de-normalize the files, but this can a bit tricky to maintain state in sync. It can also flood the index DB.

Any thought?